# How can I add an array to an object but filter out all but one column for each array element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array on my page called `answers` that looks like this:

```
answers[{x: 1, r: true;},{x: 2,r: false;},{x: 3, r: true;}]
```

Hopefully I wrote this correctly. There are a variable number of rows in the answers array (this time it's three but it could be anything under ten). Each row contains an `x` field and a `r` field.

Can someone tell me how I can add the answers array (or recreate another similar one) but ONLY the r field of each row of the answers array to the following object:

```
$scope.so.xHeaders[fromParams]
```

Comment: You want to create a new array, containing only the `r` fields of the other in it?

Comment: Can you use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need there are a couple of ways of doing this.

```
var answers = [{x: 1, r: true},{x: 2, r: false},{x: 3, r: true}]
```

1) If you just want an array of values:

```
var arr = answers.map(function(el){
  return el.r;
}, []);

console.log(arr) // [true, false, true]
```

2) If you want to return the objects but only containing the `r` value:

```
var arr = answers.map(function(el){
  var obj = {};
  obj.r = el.r;
  return obj;
}, []);
```

(or shorter):

```
var arr = answers.map(function(el){
  return { r: el.r };
}, []);

console.log(arr) // [Object { r=true}, Object { r=false}, Object { r=true}]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Ccws7/5/).

Comment: Your 3rd answer is exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method in Underscore.js:

```
var newList = _.pluck(answers, 'r');
```

Comment: I wish we could use Underscore but we are not using it. thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
$scope.so.xHeaders = []
angular.forEach(answers, function(value, index) {
    $scope.so.xHeaders.push({ r: value.r });
});
```